# Reference two different tables depending on data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, code-first

Whats the best way to solve this.

I have one table with details from private persons and one table with details from companies.
Now i need to create a table called sales. This table will either reference the persons table or the companies table depending on if its a private person or a company that bought something.
What would be the best way to do this? Copy the data from the company/private person into the sales table?

I am using EF CF and MS-SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Please do not add EF CF SQL, that is what tags are for

Comment: What is different about the private vs. company details? I wonder if a better solution would be to combine these tables. Or to have an entities table which just has the ID and type, and the other tables (sales, details etc.) can all point back to that. A sale doesn't have to be tied to a person's middle name or a company's address, just to the person's or company's ID.

Comment: No that is not possible. They contain slightly different fields. About 7 different fields each.

Answer (score 0):

You could create two many-to-many tables `company_sales` and `person_sales` OR you could add two columns to the sales table and use `case when companyId is null then person.name`

```
person
======
personId
name
address

company
=======
companyId
name
address

sales
=====
salesId
productId
amount

person_sales
============
personId
salesId

company_sales
=============
companyId
salesId
```